# How do I get the key up/down directive working on a list in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
app.directive('ngUp', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keyup", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 40) {
                  console.log('down')
                }
            else if (event.which === 38) {
                  console.log('up');
                }
            else {
                console.log('some other');
            }

        });
    };
});
```

And I have:

```
<div  class="scrollbar" id="ex3">
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="video in videos">
            <a href="#" ng-click="select($index)" style="font-size: 100%">
                {{video.name | subStringFilter : 20}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

if I put ng-up on li element element or the anchor element I get my element in the directive as **a.ng-binding**.

I have no idea what this is.

What I want is to be able to scroll up and down my list using my up and down arrow keys (and apply a class to the highlighted list element as I scroll).

I was expecting the element to be either a li element or an anchor element but I get **a.ng-binding** which does no fire on up or down key presses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be aware that you need to set `tabindex` property on the `<li>` to make it able to trigger `keyup` event:

```
<li tabindex="{{$index}}">
```

Try this directive:

```
app.directive('ngUp', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      select: "&"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on("keyup", "[selectable]", function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var selectedElement = {};

        scope.$apply(function() {
          if (event.which === 40) {
            selectedElement = $this.next("[selectable]");
            if (selectedElement.length > 0) {
              scope.select({
                element: selectedElement
              });
            }
          } else if (event.which === 38) {
            selectedElement = $this.prev("[selectable]");
            if (selectedElement.length > 0) {
              scope.select({
                element: $this.prev("[selectable]")
              });
            }
          } else {

          }
        });

        if (selectedElement.length > 0) {
          $this.blur();
          selectedElement.focus();
        }

      });
    }
  }
});
```

Use it in the html:

```
<ul ng-up select="select(element)">
      <li selectable ng-repeat="video in videos" tabindex="{{$index}}" ng-click="select($event.target)" ng-class="{selected:video.selected}">
        <a href="#" style="font-size: 100%">
                {{video.name }}
            </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ur3bpAbXiRVosY6QBsKm?p=preview) (click to select an element, from then you can use up and down arrow to select)

**Explanation**:

In my opinion, this directive should be specified on the list items **container element** (in this case is `<ul>`), and any selectable items must be applied an attribute `selectable`. In order to make the directive reusable, this directive only takes care of handling `keyup` event and select the element, the implementation detail of how the element is selected should be passed as a function:

```
scope: {
    select: "&"
}
```

Whenever I need to select an element, I call this bound function:

```
scope.select({
                    element: $this.prev("[selectable]")
          });
```

In this example, I assume that the logic to set an element as selected is as follows:

```
$scope.select = function(element) {
    angular.forEach($scope.videos, function(value) {
      value.selected = false;
    });

    angular.element(element).scope().video.selected = true;
};
```

Comment: Thank Khanh, this is a brilliant solution. I am new to angularjs so thank you so much for the help. I read somewhere that we should avoid using JQuery, it that possible with the solution you provided?

Comment: @JD.  Angular directives are designed to wrap 3rd components (jQuery, bootstrap,...). I don't think we cannot use jQuery here.

Comment: Thank you Khanh, for all your help and guidance.

Comment: I disagree that angular directives are designed to wrap 3rd party components, although it is one option.  This is also completely solvable without jquery.

Comment: there is also no need to give tabindex an index from the list, just do tabindex="-1" and it will work as expected

Comment: @Ryan M: You can use directive to wrap 3rd party components if you use those components. I agree that this is solvable without jquery, but jquery helps us with some handy functions, so why not? Maybe you have a solution using only angular without any 3rd party library?

Comment: @Ryan M: using tabindex="-1" is also a solution. It depends on what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex . This is just one example.